# How to serialize Uint8List to json with json_annotation in Dart?

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I made a simple class that has an `Uint8List` member:

```
import "package:json_annotation/json_annotation.dart";
part "openvpn.g.dart";

@JsonSerializable()
class OpenVPN extends VPN {
  OpenVPN(Uint8List profile) {
    this.profile = profile;
  }
  /...
  Uint8List profile = null;
```

However, when running build runner on it to generate the json serializers, I get:

```
Could not generate `fromJson` code for `profile`.
None of the provided `TypeHelper` instances support the defined type.
package:my_app/folder/openvpn.dart:19:13
   ╷
19 │   Uint8List profile = null;
   │             ^^^^^^^
```

Is there a way to write my own serializer for this type? Or is there an easier way?
I don't want to have a string on the json file, I want to have the actual bytes. It's a small file so it makes sense to store as an array of bytes inside a json.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `OpenVPN` serialization method, convert the `Uint8List` into a `List<int>`. Depending on your implementation, it may look something like:

```dart
class OpenVPN {
  factory OpenVPN.fromJson(dynamic map) {
    return OpenVPN(
        ...
        profile: Uint8List.fromList(map['profile'] ?? []),
    );
  }

  toJson() {
    return {
      ...
      'profile': profile as List<int>,
    };
  }
}
```

Answer (score 17):

First, add a custom JSON converter for `Uint8List`:

```dart
import "dart:typed_data";

import "package:json_annotation/json_annotation.dart";

/// Converts to and from [Uint8List] and [List]<[int]>.
class Uint8ListConverter implements JsonConverter<Uint8List?, List<int>?> {
  /// Create a new instance of [Uint8ListConverter].
  const Uint8ListConverter();

  
  @override
  Uint8List? fromJson(List<int>? json) {
    if (json == null) return null;

    return Uint8List.fromList(json);
  }

  @override
  List<int>? toJson(Uint8List? object) {
    if (object == null) return null;

    return object.toList();
  }
```

Use `Uint8ListConverter` on Uint8List property. In your case:

```dart
import 'dart:typed_data';

import 'package:json_annotation/json_annotation.dart';

import 'uint8_list_converter.dart';

part 'open_vpn.g.dart';

@JsonSerializable(explicitToJson: true)
class OpenVPN {
  OpenVPN({this.profile});

  @Uint8ListConverter()
  Uint8List? profile = null;

  factory OpenVPN.fromJson(Map<String, Object?> json) =>
      _$OpenVPNFromJson(json);

  Map<String, Object?> toJson() => _$OpenVPNToJson(this);
}
```

In the project root, run this command in a terminal to generate the `open_vpn.g.dart` part-file: `dart run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs`

Comment: I get two errors for this code on each of the return null lines: "A value of type 'Null' can't be returned from the method 'fromJson' because it has a return type of 'Uint8List'" and "A value of type 'Null' can't be returned from the method 'toJson' because it has a return type of 'List<int>'".