# How to store List<UInt8List> in objectbox flutter

Tags: flutter, objectbox

I want to store List of Uint8list in objectBox flutter
could you tell me how could i do this

Thank you

Comment: This sounds like a byte array, which should be supported already?

Comment: no datatype is not supported

Comment: Uint8List is among the supported types. But it needs to be a property of an entity class. Maybe try https://docs.objectbox.io/getting-started.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store a list of something other than String in ObjectBox, you need to use a property converter

https://docs.objectbox.io/advanced/custom-types

To create a property converter, add a getter and setter for a new variable, named with the letters `db` before your property name. Ex. for`myList`, you will add `List<Uint8List> get dbMyList` and `set dbMyList(List<Uint8List>)`.

In the case of a `List<Uint8List>`, I would recommend serializing each `Uint8List` to JSON and saving the resulting `List<String>`. [Here is an answer describing how to implement a json converter for Uint8List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63716036/how-to-serialize-uint8list-to-json-with-json-annotation-in-dart).

Answer (score -1):

somethin like this init

```
import 'dart:typed_data';

void main() {
  
  List<int> list = [];
  
  Uint8List bytes1 = Uint8List.fromList([1,2,3]);
  
  Uint8List bytes2 = Uint8List.fromList([4,5,6]);
  
  list.addAll(bytes1);
  list.addAll(bytes2);

  print(list);
  
}
```